# How to return the variable back to the object of the class which it is called in php...I want to print the order number in html input field

Tags: php, html

This is the page where i call the object

```
<?php

$orderno = new order();
$orderno->order_no();

?>
```

This is the page where I created my class

```
class order extends db
{

    function order_no()
    {
        $auto_gen = mysqli_query($this->connection,"SELECT MAX(Order_No) AS order_number FROM o_master");
        $orderno = mysqli_fetch_array($auto_gen);
        $get_orderno = $orderno['order_number'];

        $prefix ="";

        if($get_orderno == "")
        {
            $prefix = "A0001";
            return $prefix;
        }
        else
        {
            $char ="A000";
            $number = mysqli_query($this->connection,"SELECT MAX(Order_ID) AS order_number FROM o_master");
            $o_id = mysqli_fetch_array($number);
            $o_no = $o_id['order_number'];
            $get_no = $o_no + 1;
            $prefix = $char.$get_no;
            return $prefix;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `echo $orderno->order_no();` currently you do nothing with the returned variable, probably you want to echo it or save it

Comment: I want to echo it

Comment: so does typing `echo` as i suggested work? If not you need to explain your problem better

Comment: Didn't echoed....
Nothing Shows in the textbox

Comment: I didn't passed anything to page to which the function that I called....

Comment: Turn on error reporting and check your error logs.

Comment: How to do that?? As I'm new to php

Comment: try `echo '<pre>'.print_r($orderno->order_no()).'</pre>'` see what that displays on your page.